# OpenStack AutoPilotBeta: on Dell R610 servers - Any work around for the disk size can't be 'NoneType' issue?

Tags: juju, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I am trying to utilize AutoPilotBeta to deploy OpenStack on 8 Dell servers. The servers are a mix of R610, R415, R815, and R310 models. Some of these servers report DVD, CD, and NVRam as Disk in response to the `lshw` command, but do not report size. I have gotten to the point in the process where I have a MAAS configured and all of the servers are commissioned. When I execute the "openstack-install", it completes successfully. When I go to the `https://<my-server-ip>/account/standalone/openstack/` page, I am able to login and I have all green checkmarks. I click  and I get all of the options to configure my cloud except the physical zones. when I check the error log on the server that is running Landscape, I see the following:

```
File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/openstack/jobs.py", line 260, in run
disk_size = sum(int(disk["size"]) for disk in disks)
File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/openstack/jobs.py", line 260, in <genexpr>
disk_size = sum(int(disk["size"]) for disk in disks)
exceptions.TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

I tried querying the the API for the same node the threw the error ... I am pretty sure this is the section that caused it:

```
  <node id="disk:0" claimed="true" class="disk" handle="SCSI:00:00:00:00">
   <description>SCSI Disk</description>
   <physid>0</physid>
   <businfo>scsi@0:0.0.0</businfo>
   <logicalname>/dev/sdc</logicalname>
   <dev>8:32</dev>
   <configuration>
    <setting id="sectorsize" value="512" />
   </configuration>
  </node>
```

No mention of size anywhere ... since it is a driver for USB storage that is not plugged in, so it has no size ...

Is there a known work around for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: 06 Apr 2015:  As of this date, the [official instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack) are now installing [LDS 15.01](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ReleaseNotes15.01) that gets around this problem.

---

I believe you are running into [github issue 374](https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/374) which has been addressed in [LDS 15.01](https://help.landscape.canonical.com/LDS/ReleaseNotes15.01).

Notice in the release notes that upgrading the juju deployed LDS is not directly supported (though it can be done if you follow the non-quickstart upgrade steps closely and understand a bit about juju).

Instead, we recommend installing fresh.  You can follow these steps for something very quick (after releasing the resources already allocated in MAAS):

```
sudo apt-get install juju-quickstart
juju quickstart u/landscape/landscape-dense-maas/12

# After it's done... get the ip address of the apache2 node:
juju status apache2

# And connect to that in your web browser
```

Comment: This was exactly the information that I have been looking for.

Comment: Just for the sake of anybody else who may run into this issue and, like me, is unable to find the way around it. I made it to step 5 of the official instructions and then was stopped and there was no clear path to a solution. I needed to copy the credentials from the ~/.juju/environments.yaml file, then perform a "sudo openstack-install -u" to clean out the failed install, then I had to bootstrap juju, following the instructions provided for doing that.Then I followed the instructions above.

Comment: It tried to throw me into a text-based browser session with the juju admin interface, I just connected to it an accepted what it was telling me. After that, I issues a sudo juju status apache2 (as described above). That gave me the IP address of the landscape server. I connected to it and was able to add my nodes to my physical zone! Once again, Thank you!

Comment: I just pushed new packages to stable ppa that will have the latest Autopilot from here on out